# Проблема получения контекста во фрагменте

Tags: java, android

Код фрагмента:

```
public ListView favoritesList;
CustomListViewAdapter myArrayAdapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageButton main_training_button = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_training_button);
    main_training_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_active_run_black_24dp);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    
    favoritesList = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.favoritesList);
    myArrayAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.custom_list_view, listItems);
    favoritesList.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
```

Код адаптера:

```
public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<ListItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал `getActivity(), getContext(), inflater.getContext(), this, MainActivity.this`. Но не работает

Comment: Наверное, не стоит пытаться делать что-либо после вызова `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TPMS extends Fragment {
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tpms, container, false);
            LF_wheel_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.LF_wheel_text);
            ************
            return view;
        }
}
```

дальше используй

```
getActivity()
```